# why the time stamp is not displayed as it is in the database when i try to use it in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

my displayed currentStamp: **2017-07-11T18:30:00.000Z**

what do i expect as a output:**2017-07-12 11:33:58**

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, date and time is separated with a capital T. UTC time is defined with a capital letter Z.

```
new Date("2017-07-11T18:30:00.000Z")
```

equals to:

```
Tue Jul 11 2017 20:30:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Comment: how to get the exact time without T and Z

Answer (score 0):

JS dosen't have DateFormatter in build options. but there are some npm packages to do that like `dataformat`.
here is the normal js code to do what you want.

```
var x = new Date();
var d = new Date(x.toISOString()),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
        hour = d.getHours();
        min = d.getMinutes();
        sec = d.getSeconds();

var output = (year + "-") + 
            (month.length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) + "-" + 
            (day.length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) + " " + 
            (hour.length == 1 ? '0' + hour : hour) + ":" + 
            (min.length == 1? '0' + min : min) +":" + 
            (sec.length == 1? '0' +sec : sec);
```

here I put the code with normal js date. but you have to take the date from the mysql. 
Hope this will help full. Thanks